# extracting certificate from smart card using silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, cryptography, client, smartcard

I want to know, is it possible to get certificate from smart card from web browser through silverlight. If it is possible please give some directions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in browser mode. Trusted out-of-browser applications can use p/invoke to call PKCS#11 drivers or CryptoAPI, but this is not possible for in-browser stuff.

Comment: The info about this is very poor in the web. If i dont mix up, after inserting the smart card the certificate from it is copied to certificate store on the machine. Maybe it is possible to reach it there (through sl)? What you think?

Comment: @Brick The certificate is not copied, it's just exposed via CryptoAPI. Also, the private key is not available that way. In this aspect Silverlight is very limited.